# How do you use the blending tool on a curved object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending

How would I go about blending straight lines into a curved object like this? I basically want to make a geometric feather with the lines beginning at the bottom vertex growing outwards towards the arc.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Do you really need a blend??

If you want the **sides straight**, This can be done with `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform`:

[image]

Note the settings in the Transform Effect Dialog window. 
<sup>(the window may look different based upon the AI version, but all the same options exist.)</sup>

The *tricky part with the effect* is to create enough copies and a good degree of rotation, so the "other" side mirrors the angle of the original path. It may take a some experimenting by slightly tweaking the angle of the base path before applying the Effect.

---

---

In any event....

#### .... for a Blend.....

You really *can't* create a curved blend with *only* the Blend feature. The paths for the basis of the blend need to match the desired end paths.

---

If the desire is to have **curved sides**...

##### Method 1

- Draw 3 paths - left (curved), center (straight), right (curved - or just reflect the left path) - then blend those three paths
  [image]
  This method is generally *much* easier than trying the alter the blend (so it remains symmetrical) after the fact.

---

##### Method B

- Create a blend of straight paths - then curve the outer left and right paths (after the blend is in place)
  [image]
   I aligned the three bottom anchors, then changed the end anchors on the left and right to smooth anchors, then extended the Bezier handle on each anchor the same distance.

---

For (either) method, after the blend is in place, extend the center path to give the top more volume.

[image]

*However*, it's **not possible** to make the top *curved* to match your sample image merely using a blend like this.

To create a curved top edge, one would need to either **A)** expand the blend then adjust the end points for the individual paths, or **B)** use a clipping mask or some other masking feature to *hide* parts of the paths creating a curve.

---

If you *really* want to use a blend and also want the **sides straight**:

- 3 *separate* open paths with bottom anchors aligned, then blend, extend the center path, add clipping mask for curve:

[image]

Clipping mask in outline mode:

[image]

<sub>(One *can* extend the center path *before* applying the blend. I merely did it after the blend for clarity.)</sub>

Comment: This was an awesome explanation! I will give all these methods a try. Thank you!